# Changed file name and lost editing--can old version of file's previous name be recovered

Tags: microsoft-word

I was highlighted text in a document that is a foreign language. I finished marking where I needed to get clarifications, and changed the file name (not 'save as' a new file name, but I changed the name of the file when closed). Opening the file this morning, all of the highlights are gone. There are no previous versions of the new file name as it was only created last night. In the auto recover folder, there is only one old file that only contains the first highlight I made.

Can old versions of the previous file name be recovered.

Comment: I suspect you are out of luck.  You might want to save your work more frequently in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no.

You can try a free software called recuva and try to save the recovered file to a flash drive.